# How to pass date input to php from form.It gives output as 1970-01-01

Tags: php, html

Here  is an input form which passes date type to intermediate.php from a form.

```
<form action="intermediate.php" method="post">
<input type="date" name="vazhipadudate1" />
</form>
```

How can i get the picked date i tried this code snippet .It echos as `1970-01-01`

Php code snippet.

```
$date='vazhipadudate1';
$time = strtotime($_POST["$date"]);
$storecart[$i]['date'] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
echo "Selected Date is..........".$storecart[$i]['date'] ;
```

The output i am getting as

Selected Date is..........1970-01-01

Comment: @IvoP actually, it should be `$_POST["vazhipadudate1"]` - look at the "name" attribute of the `<input` field.

Comment: ADyson  same thing throgh `"$date"` -> `"vazhipadudate1"`

Comment: @aXuser264 so it is, sorry, I didn't see the `$` in the `"$date"`.

Comment: In that case a possible explanation is that the value in the POST array is not in a format understood by strtotime. The manual has sections on the accepted formats here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php . Can we see a sample of the contents of your POST array please?

Comment: @ADyson I think i can get some clue from your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing the problem,

I think the problem is probably because your submitting the form without passing any value to `input`.
As The `input` has no def value. So it, `POST`s **empty string**.

And when you pass the empty string to `strtotime` that returns `false` 
Amd, again when you pass it to `date` that returns `1970-01-01` as `(int) FALSE` -> `0`

So you should test the `POST` before processing it. Something like this to check `POST`ed data,

```
!empty( $_POST["vazhipadudate1"] )  
# AND/OR,
$time = strtotime($_POST["$date"]);
if (time === false) /*TakeAppropriateAction*/;
```

Comment: what about if the data is not in a recognised format?

Comment: @ADyson whaaat browser is taking input and posting the time. SO, how is it supposed to be in a unrecofnised format ??

Comment: @aXuser264 I think there is some problem with the format .It is not working .How can i accept your answer

Comment: @somanraj it worked it my reproduced example, please, add the samples of `$_POST["$date"]` and  `$time`

Comment: Actually it's a good point, for a "date" input it ought to always be submitted in y-m-d format already (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) - so it's not clear why OP even needs to  convert it. (I was thinking of before that existed and it would just be a plain text field where anything could potentially be entered). Although the possibility of a non-browser client being used or user mangling the request should also be considered, so validation should still be applied really.

Comment: @ADyson isn't `strtotime($_POST["$date"]) === false`  enough for validation ?

Comment: @aXuser264 yes it is I believe. But I think you were suggesting an invalid date would be an impossible situation due to the input type="date". Which is true when the HTML form is used, but not for other cases. So I think we're now in agreement.